# Adding values out of a textarea in an array

Tags: php, arrays, math

I am learning how to code OOP at the moment and I am building some math related tools for it. Starting of simple with calculating the average value and the median etc.

Here's my problem: I want the visitor to be able to fill in all their values at once in a text area, catch those values and store them in an array.

The storing in an array part does work, but it stores them in an array in a way I cannot calculate anything further with them.

This is the way I want it to happen:

```
array(2){0=> 2, 1=> 5)
```

This is the way it does:

```
array(1){0=> 2,5}
```

This is my code:

```
public function calculateAverage(){
    $arrValues = array();
    array_push($arrValues, $_POST['averageForm']);
    var_dump($arrValues);
    foreach($arrValues as $id => $key){
        $TotalSum += $key;
    }

    $Average = $TotalSum/ count($arrValues);

    return $Average;
}
```

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do

```
$arrValues = explode(',', $_POST['averageForm']);
```

what you were doing with `array_push()` is adding `$_POST['averageForm']` to the end of the array. Since the array didn't have any values appended to it yet, `$_POST['averageForm']` got assigned to `$arrValues[0]`.

Comment: btw, maybe its smart to typecast `$key` in the foreach loop to `(int)`, this will prevent you from getting any errors